# system.reflection.targetexception: 'non-static method requires a target

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am getting the error message "system.reflection.targetexception: 'non-static method requires a target.'

it breaks because the Scheme object is null. I'm trying to handle this in the Where() clause but it still throwing the same exception.

Any Advice?

`code`

```
ViewBag.LibraryTypeVersionID = (from ltv in _db.LibraryTypeVersions
                                            let schemeLibraries = _db.SchemeLibraryTypes
                                            .Where(x=> (scheme == null || x.IdScheme == scheme.IdScheme))
                                            .Select(x => x.IdLibraryTypeVersion).ToList()
                                            select new
                                            {
                                                LibraryName = ltv.LibraryType.LibraryName,
                                                IdLibraryTypeVersion = ltv.IdLibraryTypeVersion,
                                                Version = ltv.Version,
                                                SchemeIdLibraryVersion = schemeLibraries
                                            }).OrderByDescending(x => x.LibraryName)
                          .ToGroupedSelectList(
                x => x.LibraryName,
                x => x.LibraryName + " - " + x.Version,
                x => x.IdLibraryTypeVersion,
                x => x.SchemeIdLibraryVersion.Contains(x.IdLibraryTypeVersion));***emphasized text***
```

`code`

Comment: Try .Where(x=> (scheme != null && x.IdScheme == scheme.IdScheme))

Comment: Hi Olaf, thanks for your prompt response. However the exception is the same.